# processing date and time data in R

Tags: r

Dear all, I have a data frame which comes directly from a sensor. The data provide the date and time in a single column. I want R to be able to recognise this data and then create an adjacent column in the data frame which gives a number that corresponds to a new day in the time and date column. For example 25/02/2011 13:34 in data$time.date would give 1 in the new column data$day, and 26/02/2011 13:34 in data$time.date would get 2 and so on....

Does anyone know how to go about solving this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: some dummy data to illustrate your data, frequency of observation etc. would have elevated your Q a bit. From a previous Q I guess this is a YSI sonde or similar with many observations per day or even hour? See my answer for illustration on how to produce a dummy data set that you could have used in your Q.

Comment: You don't say what you're ultimately trying to accomplish, but you would probably benefit from putting your time series data in a time series class object (e.g. xts) instead of a data.frame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `cut()` <strike>and convert to numeric the factor resulting from that call</strike>. Here is an example with dummy data:

```
> sdate <- as.POSIXlt("25/02/2011 13:34", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
> edate <- as.POSIXlt("02/03/2011 13:34", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
> df <- data.frame(dt = seq(from = sdate, to = edate, by = "hours"))
> head(df)
                   dt
1 2011-02-25 13:34:00
2 2011-02-25 14:34:00
3 2011-02-25 15:34:00
4 2011-02-25 16:34:00
5 2011-02-25 17:34:00
6 2011-02-25 18:34:00
```

We cut the date time column into days using `cut()`. <strike>This results in a factor with the dates as labels. We convert this factor to numerics to get `1, 2, ...`</strike>:

```
> df <- within(df, day <- cut(dt, "day", labels = FALSE))
> head(df, 13)
                    dt day
1  2011-02-25 13:34:00   1
2  2011-02-25 14:34:00   1
3  2011-02-25 15:34:00   1
4  2011-02-25 16:34:00   1
5  2011-02-25 17:34:00   1
6  2011-02-25 18:34:00   1
7  2011-02-25 19:34:00   1
8  2011-02-25 20:34:00   1
9  2011-02-25 21:34:00   1
10 2011-02-25 22:34:00   1
11 2011-02-25 23:34:00   1
12 2011-02-26 00:34:00   2
13 2011-02-26 01:34:00   2
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Does exactly what I'm after. Brilliant.

Comment: Note that conversion to numeric is not needed. Just use the `labels=FALSE` argument to `cut.POSIXt`.

Comment: @Gab_27 you've asked a couple of Qs now and haven't accepted an answer on either despite leaving comments to say an answer solved you problem. When you look at the answers you should see a blank tick beneath the number of votes on the left. Tick that if an answer solves your Q. This is useful because others who come across your Q via a search will know if any of the answers solved the Q for you. This is you doing your little bit for the community here on SO.

Comment: I see, thanks for letting me know about this, I was not aware.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using cut.POSIXt. For example:

```
dat <- data.frame(datetimes = Sys.time() - seq(360000, 0, by=-3600))
dat$day <- cut(dat$datetimes, breaks="day", labels=FALSE)
```

Note that this assumes your date time column is correclty formated as a date-time class.

See `?DateTimeClasses` for details.